# How to paint the rows in a GridView ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, paint

I am a beginner in ASP.NET

I dont have idea of how to do this, pleas help me

Until now I only have the code for filtering the gridview but does not not work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.buscar').each(function (i) {
            $(this).quicksearch("[id*=grdProductos] tr:not(:has(th))", {
                'testQuery': function (query, txt, row) {
                    return $(row).children(":eq(" + 3 + ")").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query[0].toLowerCase()) != -1;
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```